# How to set a Django filter to select all

Tags: python, django

I have a view in Django that will read a get request and its parameters and make a query based on the parameters. Currently my view looks like this:

```
def getInventory(request):
    c = request.GET.get('category', '')
    g = request.GET.get('gender', '')
    s = request.GET.get('size', '')

    available = Item.objects.filter(gender=g,category=c,size=s)
    data = serializers.serialize('json',available)
    return HttpResponse(data,'json')
```

Sometimes, though, one of the parameters is not specified. I would like this to result in a value representing 'all' rather than an individual value. Is this possible in the way I've done it? I've tried `gender=None` but that just results in an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply a filter only if you want to filter something. You could do something like this:

```
# Start off with a base queryset
available = Item.objects.all()

allowed_filters = ['category', 'gender', 'size']
for f in allowed_filters:
    if request.GET.get(f):
        available = available.filter(**{f: request.GET[f]})

data = serializers.serialize('json',available)
return HttpResponse(data,'json')
```

That said, you might want to consider using the [Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/) to validate the inputs before passing them to your queryset.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.